# edk2 build error /nologo tbuild failed to build winhost in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, edk2

I am a newbie to edk2, and I am trying to setup and build the edk2 as explained in the following link [edk2 tutorial wiki](https://github.com/tianocore training/Tianocore_Training_Contents/wiki).

but when I say

> $ build -D ADD_SHELL_STRING -a X64 -p EmulatorPkg/EmulatorPkg.dsc

I see the following error log, I dont understand the error properly so
I have pasted the log as follows

---

GenFfs -t EFI_FV_FILETYPE_DRIVER -g CCCB0C28-4B24-11d5-9A5A-0090273FC14D -o c:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\FV\Ffs\CCCB0C28-4B24-11d5-9A5A-0090273FC14DGraphicsConsoleDxe\CCCB0C28-4B24-11d5-9A5A-0090273FC14D.ffs -oi c:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\FV\Ffs\CCCB0C28-4B24-11d5-9A5A-0090273FC14DGraphicsConsoleDxe\CCCB0C28-4B24-11d5-9A5A-0090273FC14DSEC2.com
Creating library c:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\X64\MdeModulePkg\Bus\Pci\PciBusDxe\PciBusDxe\DEBUG\PciBusDxe.lib and object c:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\X64\MdeModulePkg\Bus\Pci\PciBusDxe\PciBusDxe\DEBUG\PciBusDxe.exp
if exist c:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\FV\Ffs\6d6963ab-906d-4a65-a7ca-bd40e5d6af2bUdp4Dxe\6d6963ab-906d-4a65-a7ca-bd40e5d6af2bSEC2.com.dummy GenSec -s EFI_SECTION_COMPRESSION -c PI_STD -o c:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\FV\Ffs\6d6963ab-906d-4a65-a7ca-bd40e5d6af2bUdp4Dxe\6d6963ab-906d-4a65-a7ca-bd40e5d6af2bSEC2.com c:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\FV\Ffs\6d6963ab-906d-4a65-a7ca-bd40e5d6af2bUdp4Dxe\6d6963ab-906d-4a65-a7ca-bd40e5d6af2bSEC2.com.dummy
Generating code
GenFfs -t EFI_FV_FILETYPE_DRIVER -g 6d6963ab-906d-4a65-a7ca-bd40e5d6af2b -o c:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\FV\Ffs\6d6963ab-906d-4a65-a7ca-bd40e5d6af2bUdp4Dxe\6d6963ab-906d-4a65-a7ca-bd40e5d6af2b.ffs -oi c:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\FV\Ffs\6d6963ab-906d-4a65-a7ca-bd40e5d6af2bUdp4Dxe\6d6963ab-906d-4a65-a7ca-bd40e5d6af2bSEC2.com
Building ... c:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\EmulatorPkg\EmuBusDriverDxe\EmuBusDriverDxe.inf [X64]
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\Hostx86\x64\cl.exe" /Foc:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\X64\EmulatorPkg\EmuBusDriverDxe\EmuBusDriverDxe\OUTPUT.\ /showIncludes /nologo /c /WX /GS- /W4 /Gs32768 /D UNICODE /O1b2s /GL /Gy /FIAutoGen.h /EHs-c- /GR- /GF /Z7 /Gw -D DISABLE_NEW_DEPRECATED_INTERFACES /Od /Oy- /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\EmulatorPkg\EmuBusDriverDxe  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\X64\EmulatorPkg\EmuBusDriverDxe\EmuBusDriverDxe\DEBUG  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\MdePkg  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\MdePkg\Include  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\MdePkg\Test\UnitTest\Include  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\MdePkg\Include\X64  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\EmulatorPkg  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\EmulatorPkg\Include @c:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\X64\EmulatorPkg\EmuBusDriverDxe\EmuBusDriverDxe\OUTPUT\cc_resp_2.txt
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\Hostx86\x64\cl.exe" /Foc:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\X64\EmulatorPkg\Win\Host\WinHost\OUTPUT.\ /showIncludes /nologo /c /WX /GS- /W4 /Gs32768 /D UNICODE /O1b2s /GL /Gy /FIAutoGen.h /EHs-c- /GR- /GF /Z7 /Gw /nologo /W4 /WX /Gy /c /D UNICODE /Od /Oy- /FIAutoGen.h /EHs-c- /GF /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D DISABLE_NEW_DEPRECATED_INTERFACES /Od /Oy- /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\EmulatorPkg\Win\Host  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\X64\EmulatorPkg\Win\Host\WinHost\DEBUG  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\MdePkg  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\MdePkg\Include  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\MdePkg\Test\UnitTest\Include  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\MdePkg\Include\X64  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\MdeModulePkg  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\MdeModulePkg\Include  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\NetworkPkg  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\NetworkPkg\Include  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\EmulatorPkg  /Ic:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\EmulatorPkg\Include @c:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\X64\EmulatorPkg\Win\Host\WinHost\OUTPUT\cc_resp_8.txt' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
Finished generating code

build.py...
: error 7000: Failed to execute command
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\Hostx86\x86\nmake.exe /nologo tbuild [c:\fw\edk2-ws\Build\EmulatorX64\DEBUG_VS2019\X64\EmulatorPkg\Win\Host\WinHost]

build.py...
: error F002: Failed to build module
c:\fw\edk2-ws\edk2\EmulatorPkg\Win\Host\WinHost.inf [X64, VS2019, DEBUG]

- Failed -
  Build end time: 14:57:26, May.23 2023
  Build total time: 00:04:16

---

I followed the [build setup download edk2](https://github.com/tianocore-training/Presentation_FW/blob/main/FW/Presentations/_C_01_Build_Setup_Download_EDK_II_Win_Lab.pdf) but ended up with an error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited my question again, Basically what im trying to say is I am not able to build the edk2, it throws some error following the command (build -t VS2019 -a X64). I am not able to understand the error so that is why I pasted the log. Although as an update, when I tried building (build -t VS2019 -a IA32) it builds successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio toolchains keep changing the command line options and defaults between releases. For building with the VS2019 profile, you need a toolchain version in the 16.x series, but your output suggests you have a 14.x installed - meaning VS2015, `-t VS2015`, should work.